# Can't use 'flow_from_directory' because it doesn't seems to exist

Tags: ubuntu, machine-learning, keras, python-3.6

Using Ubuntu, python3.6
I'm trying to use flow_from_directory for the first time but it doesn't work even after trying to use it outside my code and with change in the arguments.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

categoris = ['cat', 'dog']

def create_train_test_data(WIDTH = 128, HEIGHT = 128, test_size_input = 0.2, numcategories = 1, sizeset = 512):

    dlist = {}
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
    for i in range(0,numcategories):
        dlist[categoris[i] + '_files'] = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/train_orig/' + numcategoris[i] + '*', target_size=(WIDTH, HEIGHT), batch_size=sizeset, class_mode=None)
```

All i get is:

```
AttributeError: 'ImageDataGenerator' object has no attribute 'flow_from_directory'
```

and

```
ImageDataGenerator()
```

doesn't accept any arguments

Also this is my first Question about on stack and about computing.

Comment: what is your version of keras? I believe you're using and old version in which the method did not exist

Comment: That's it, I updated keras and it work now.
Thanks.